# Delete article only if the url provided by the user matched the url of the article

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a confirmation popup in github which asks for the repository url , and unless we provide the correct url the repository is not deleted/destroyed. Please guide me how can I achieve it if I want to have this feature in my ruby on rails project

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: You can do it purely on the client side using Javascript. Add an event handler to the delete button which prompts the user for confirmation before actually sending the request.

Comment: But I have to stop the destroy function in the controller which is called in the destroy action according to the user input if the user input is not correct @maxpleaner

Comment: But I have to stop m.destroy in the controller's destroy action in rails if the user inuput is not correct. Please share a code @maxpleaner

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a delete button like this:

```
<%= button_to "Destroy", things_path(@thing),
    method: :delete,
    data: { name: @thing.name },
    class: "delete-btn"
%>
```

You can add a Javascript confirmation like so:

```
$(".delete-btn").on("click", function(event) {
  var name = $(event.currentTarget).data("name")
  var confirmation = prompt("enter name of repo to delete");
  if (confirmation != name) {
    event.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

If you want to imitate github you need to use a modal instead of a prompt, but this is just to give you an idea of one way

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you

Comment: thanx for your help